# Unit test on program which has lots of macros

Tags: c, unit-testing, refactoring

Recently, I need to add unit test to one legacy program.

But in it, there are lots of macros, like

```
#ifdef CONFIG_XXX
do xxx
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_YYY
do yyy
#endif
```

Currently, the generic program path are covered by unit tests. So, I want to add tests to cover the inside macro parts (different program path).

It seems that I need to compile and run my program with certain macros each time, and how to design the composition of macros to cover the program path and reduce compilation times is really not easy.

So, I plan to move all the hardware related code to arch folder, now, macros were moved from  c files to makefile, but still need to compile with certain macros each time to get UT work.

Does anyone have experiences on this problem before?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Could you consider replacing each macro with an `if (config.XXX)`? That way, you eliminate the need to recompile.

Comment: I can't, since the difference of macro and if statement.

Comment: What I mean is, refactor your code to take a `config` struct as an input. This struct could have a set of flag variables, each corresponding to one of your macros.

Comment: Sorry for the code sample, It's just an example, not mean that it's all related to the config_*, in the code base, also has other macros like AAA BBB CCC, etc.

Comment: OK. But the same principle could be applied.  Rather than choosing a code path at compile time, choose it at run time.

Comment: There's really no getting around compiling and testing all the paths.  You need to test every possible configuration you plan to ship.  This may mean the first step is making your unit test framework portable across all your delivery platforms.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can just use gcc -D to generate many version of the binary program.
compile and run them with a script to do that :)

Comment: In the question: "It seems that I need to compile and run my program with certain macros each time", gcc -D is used to just make this happen.